Singleton BMT bean for handling transactional tasks
Speaking about transactions i usually prefer to make them handled by the container.
In an old code, which made the container handle the transaction correctly, WildFly complained about the fact that i was closing a JDBC connection AFTER transaction boundaries (unregistered connection). The "error" was logged into system out at INFO level, and was a silent error (not catchable).
Now i want to make sure to handle my transactions by my self so i created the following SINGLETON/STARTUP EJB.
@Local(TransactionHandler.class)
@Singleton(name = "EJBTransactionHandler")
@Startup
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class EJBTransactionHandler extends DefaultTransactionHandler implements TransactionHandler {

    @Resource
    EJBContext ejbContext;

    @Override
    public <T, Context extends ApplicationContext> T executeTransaction(TransactionalTask<T, Context> transactionalTask, Context applicationContext, TransactionalContext transactionalContext) throws TransactionRolledBackException {
        T returnValue = null;
        try {
            ejbContext.getUserTransaction().begin();
            // Here the jdbc connection is retrieved from datasource
            onTransactionBegin(transactionalTask, applicationContext, transactionalContext);
            returnValue = applicationContext.executeTask(transactionalTask);
            // just logging, not making use of "commit" method of JDBC connection
            onTransactionCommit(transactionalTask, applicationContext, transactionalContext);
            ejbContext.getUserTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            try {
                // just logging, not making use of "rollback" method of JDBC connection
                onTransactionRollback(transactionalTask, applicationContext, transactionalContext);
            } catch (Throwable e1) {
                applicationContext.dispatchError(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    ejbContext.getUserTransaction().rollback();
                } catch (IllegalStateException | SecurityException | SystemException e1) {
                    applicationContext.dispatchError(e1);
                }
            }
            throw new TransactionRolledBackException(transactionalTask, "Transaction has been rolled back for task \"" + transactionalTask.getTaskName() + "\".", e);
        } finally {
            // making use of "close" method of JDBC connection
            onTransactionEnd(transactionalTask, applicationContext, transactionalContext);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

In this code, no commit/rollback call are made on the JDBC connections involved into the transactional task. the only method called is the "close" method of the JDBC connection inside the "onTransactionEnd" logic.
I know that in a JavaEE environment connections are pooled, so close does not actually close a connection, but i want to know if there is a specific order to be followed when closing/committing/rolling back connections.
Can i assume that the above is compliant with BMT transactions in a JavaEE Environment?
And can I assume that, since this bean is a singleton and accessed concurrently, transaction management will be consistent even if i do not make use of explicit synchronization?
Thanks.
